# "Is married" correct or wrong?

Tags: grammar

I saw in some news paper **"she is married with.... bla bla"**. Is that grammar correct ? What happen when it is change into **"she was married with...."**

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. We appreciate questions that show some research before posting, and those that are answerable in general reference are considered off-topic. If you require assistance in framing a question, please visit our [Help page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) “How to write a good question”.

Comment: *Married with* usually implies children... we need more context here. When signifying a partner it would be *married to*.

Comment: In addition to Cascabel's note, I caution you we need *complete* context to be able to answer you definitively. What words follow *with* have a big impact on determining what was the intended meaning, and it is certainly possible for a certain phrasing to be grammatically correct but semantically or idiomatically all wrong. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also interest you.

Comment: It would be useful to know ***which*** newspaper, if it was American, British, or Indian for example. It would be very useful to have a link to the article. It would also help greatly if the OP could cite the entire sentence. The question might even get a few upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For married people the expression is more normally "married **to**", e.g. "John is **married to** Alan". As an adjective you could say "John and Alan **are married**". In the past tense you'd say "John **married** Alan".

"Marry **with**" is also grammatically correct but is commonly used with impersonal objects. "**Marry** pomegranate **with** halloumi to enhance your salads".

To answer your specific question: **Is married** is, in itself, correct.

Comment: More context? Maybe _married with children_, which is very common. You could then have "When she wrote the novel, she was married with three kids and had her hands full.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - that's a good point. I read the question as marriage-with-the-object-of-the-marriage.

Answer (score 0):

It is proper grammar since it is stating that that person is married.  If after the word married comes up then that will most likely affect the grammatical side to the word.

Comment: Hi again, good to see you to, thanks I will work on that now then.